# How to capture NSSharingService close event

Tags: facebook, cocoa, twitter, sharing

When using the NSSharingService popup, searching for a solution to know when the NSSharingService is closed when canceling the action.
If the popup is closed when posting (button Post on NSSharingServiceNamePostOnFacebook or Tweet on NSSharingServiceNamePostOnTwitter) you can use the delegate:

```
- (void)sharingService:(NSSharingService *)sharingService didShareItems:(NSArray *)items
```

or the will share items one:

```
- (void)sharingService:(NSSharingService *)sharingService willShareItems:(NSArray *)items
```

but how to know when is being closed using the Close button ?

Answer (score 0):

it should trigger

```
- (void)sharingService:(NSSharingService *)sharingService didFailToShareItems:(NSArray *)items error:(NSError *)error
```

with an error value indicating that the user cancelled.